# Recurrence relation without modulo

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations

So I have this function, $f(n)$. If $n$ is odd it equals $2$, if $n$ is even it equals $1$. For example, $f(1) = 2$ and $f(2) = 1$.

I need to find a recurrence relation for this function. However, I can't figure out at all how to "properly" find one by calling $f(n-1)$. I could only find:

$$f(n) = \mod(n,2) + 1$$

Is there a way to replace the mod operator to have a proper recurrence relation that returns the same results?

EDIT: currently trying out your answers. Please post them as $$f(n) = something.

Basically I want $$f(n) when n is greater or equal to 3.

Comment: $f(n)=f(n-2)\,$?

Comment: $f(1) =2$, $f(n+1) = f(n)+(-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: Thank you @Arturo, this worked perfectly. f(n) = f(n-1) + (-1)^n+1

Comment: @Yoshi: Careful: I may have gotten the sign wrong.

Answer (score 2):

$$
f(n+1) = 3-f(n)\qquad f(1) = 2
$$

Comment: After you Malcolm: you got there just before me.$\ddot{\smile}$

Comment: Usually it's the other way around for me.  I get the idea for the answer then I notice *1 new answer*.  And nice smiley face, I will plagiarize that for sure.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(n+1)=f(n)+(-1)^n\quad\text{with }f(1)=2.$$

Answer (score 1):

You want $f(n+2)=f(n)$, so the characteristic equation is $x^2-1=0$, which has roots $1$ and $-1$. Thus the general solution is $\alpha+\beta(-1)^n$. The initial condition tells you $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=2$, so
$$
\alpha+\beta=1
\qquad
\alpha-\beta=2
$$
Therefore $\alpha=3/2$ and $\beta=-1/2$. Hence
$$
f(n)=\frac{3-(-1)^n}{2}
$$
Then
$$
f(n+1)=\frac{3-(-1)^{n+1}}{2}=\frac{3-(-1)^n}{2}+\frac{(-1)^{n}-(-1)^{n+1}}{2}
=f(n)+(-1)^n
$$
and you just need to set $f(0)=1$ or, if your natural numbers start from $1$, with $f(1)=2$.

Alternatively,
$$
f(n+1)=\frac{3-(-1)^{n+1}}{2}=\frac{3+(-1)^n}{2}=\frac{6-(3-(-1)^n)}{2}=3-f(n)
$$

Comment: f(0)  is actually undefined. The sole initial condition is f(1) = 2. f(n) represents the amount of operations a coded algorithm does, I simply figured out that f(2) = 1 and that odd numbers returned 2 while even numbers returned 1. I got the right answer but thank you for the refresher on that subject

Comment: @Tarek Then do the same with $f(1)=1$. But there's no problem in starting from $0$, which is an even number.